# Finding total number of duplicates in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am parsing through a CSV file and require your kind assistance. I have duplicates in my CSV file. I want to tell Python to provide me with the total number of Duplicate Addresses and total number of unique Addresses and then list them. I have successfully got to the part where the Address shows if it's an unique or duplicate but now I want to tell Python to provide me with the respected numbers as well.

```
import csv

csv_data = csv.reader(file('T:\DataDump\Book1.csv'))

next(csv_data)

already_seen = set()

for row in csv_data:
    Address = row[6]
    if Address in already_seen:
        print('{} is a duplicate Address'.format(Address))
    else:
        print('{} is a unique Address'.format(Address))
        already_seen.add(Address)
```

Comment: There's a lot of ways. You could increment a value when you print that it's a duplicate. You could compare the length of `always_seen` to the length of the file.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, can you please provide a little code I can use as an example? I am new to programming so still learning.

Comment: Declare a variable outside of the loop, eg `duplicate = 0` and then in the same block as you do `if address in already_seen:`, do `duplicate += 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could detect duplicates on the fly with 1 sole pass but you have to fully read the file to know if it's *not* a duplicate and to count how many duplicates there are.

So 2 passes are required here. Use `collections.Counter` like this:

```
import csv
import collections

with open(r"T:\DataDump\Book1.csv") as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")

    next(csv_data)  # skip title line

    count = collections.Counter()

    # first pass: read the file
    for row in csv_data:
        address = row[6]
        count[address] += 1

    # second pass: display duplicate info & compute total
    total_dups = 0
    for address,nb in count.items():
        if nb>1:
            total_dups += nb
            print('{} is a duplicate address, seen {} times'.format(address,nb))
        else:
            print('{} is a unique address'.format(address))
    print("Total duplicate addresses {}".format(toal_dups))
```

to print the total number of duplicate addresses you could also do directly:

```
    print("Total duplicate addresses {}".format(sum(x for x in count.values() if x > 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, when I run the script you have suggested it shows an      error.     Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/Users/Programming/addreesss.py", line 4, in <module>
         with open(r"'T:\DataDump\Book1.csv'") as f:
     IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: "'T:\\DataDump\\Book1.csv'"

Comment: Sorry, too many quotes (I tested under a different input file). Now fixed. PS: note the `r` prefix to be able to use backslashes without interpreting them.

Comment: You _don't_ have to fully read the file to determine if something is a duplicate, however you do if you want a count of the total number of them that were found.

Comment: @martineau: right. I'll edit. What I meant is you have to read fully the file before printing "this is not a duplicate" :)

Comment: Thanks Jean, this code works great. It gives me how many times an Address is there in the CSV file. Is there anyway I can have a total number of all duplicates at the top and then there details(I have this).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
my_dict = { i:My_List.count(i) for i in My_List}
```

It will return the count of every instances including duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This should be as easy as having a dictionary to store the count of addresses:

```
import csv

csv_data = csv.reader(file('T:\DataDump\Book1.csv'))
next(csv_data)

address_count = {}

for row in csv_data:
    Address = row[6]
    if Address in address_count.keys():
        print('{} is a duplicate Address'.format(Address))
        address_count[Address] = address_count[Address] + 1 
    else:
        print('{} is a unique Address'.format(Address))
        address_count[Address] = 1 

print address_count
```